# Convert pandas datetime to hours from start

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a dataframe with the following datatime index:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-17 00:00:00', '2018-10-17 01:00:00',
               '2018-10-17 02:00:00', '2018-10-17 03:00:00',
               '2018-10-17 04:00:00', '2018-10-17 05:00:00',
               '2018-10-17 06:00:00', '2018-10-17 07:00:00',
               '2018-10-17 08:00:00', '2018-10-17 09:00:00',
               ...
               '2018-11-29 15:00:00', '2018-11-29 16:00:00',
               '2018-11-29 17:00:00', '2018-11-29 18:00:00',
               '2018-11-29 19:00:00', '2018-11-29 20:00:00',
               '2018-11-29 21:00:00', '2018-11-29 22:00:00',
               '2018-11-29 23:00:00', '2018-11-30 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='dates', length=914, freq=None)
```

How do I convert it to hours from the first datetime index i.e. 0, 1, 2...

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract the the first datetime from all values in your index, then divide by `numpy.timedelta(1,'h')` (timedelta of 1 hour):

```
(df.index - df.index[0]) / np.timedelta64(1,'h')
Float64Index([   0.0,    1.0,    2.0,    3.0,    4.0,    5.0,    6.0,    7.0,
                 8.0,    9.0, 
                 ...
                 1047.0, 1048.0, 1049.0, 1050.0, 1051.0, 1052.0,
                 1053.0, 1054.0, 1055.0, 1056.0],
             dtype='float64', name='dates')
```

Comment: You can add `astype(int)` to convert it to an `Int64Index`. This is probably fine since OP seems to suggest all time components are on the hour.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to suggest that the index is such that the original timestamps are on the hour and the result should be an integer, in which case I would modify sacul's answer to something like

```
24*(idx - idx[0]).days + idx.hour
Int64Index([   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9, 1047,
        1048, 1049, 1050, 1051, 1052, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056],
       dtype='int64', name='dates')
```

and use the `components` attribute of `pandas.TimeDeltaIndex` to deal with any residual minutes, seconds, *etc.* so that you use only already exposed attributes.